# Алгоритм для расчета кратчайшего пути между 2 динамическими объектами

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, freepascal

Я пытался применить алгоритм Ли (волновой), но проблема в том, то каждый ход игрока заставляет считать путь заново, что сильно просаживает FPS. Я пробовал просто работать с последней волной (достроить еще волну или удалить последнюю), но тут тоже есть проблема, когда игрок перемещается в зону другого пути, то есть кратчайший теперь совершенно другой и связь между этими путями обрывается, то боту остается только тепнуться на новый путь.
`Кружок - игрок, зеленый квадрат - бот`
Вот бот на 1 пути.
[image: Бот на 1 пути]
Вот я двинулся правее и перешел на новый кратчайший путь, а боту остается только тепнуться.
[image: Бот на 2 пути]
А вот я еще правее двинулся и пути разорвались.
[image: Бот на 2 пути с разрывом путей]
Как можно изменить алгоритм или может есть какой-то более подходящий?

Answer (score 0):

В общем виде у вас вполне правильное решение. Если оно вас не устраивает по скорости, попробуйте оптимизировать. Например, пускать волну одного типа от бота и другого типа от цели. К моменту соединения двух волн можно остановиться. На открытом пространстве скорость будет больше, т.к. площадь у двух волн будет меньше, чем у одной, и меньше необходимо вычислений. 
 Можно разменять скорость на объем памяти и заранее рассчитать поля для различных положений цели (опять же можно считать не для каждого положения, а только для областей).

Comment: А можно пример, пожалуйста? Уже 3й день пытаюсь оптимизировать этот алгоритм, получается только хуже. У меня расчет пути занимает 250 мс, а это 4 фпс. Я мог бы просто расчитывать если на другой путь встал, но это просадка фпс получается. Как рассчитать области (какие области?) я тоже не пойму. Щас пытался сделать расчет всей карты и поиск мест, где волна расходится в несколько сторон и брал их за точки до которых надо идти боту (от точек еще волны расходятся до игрока уже), если путь был прерван (выбор точки так же через волны), но я понял, что это лишь больше нагружает и более запутанно.

Comment: 250 мс - это вы что-то неправильно делаете. На приведенном скриншоте у вас не пересчитана сетка, вообще непонятно как вы ищите путь. Волну надо пускать каждый раз, как перемещается цель. Алгоритм Ли состоит из двух частей: 1 - построение карты (пускаете волну от цели); 2 - нахождение пути (в простейшем случае движение к любой клетке с меньшим номером). Исходя из скриншотов с одинаковой волной непонятно что у вас выполняется 250 мс...

Comment: Вот статья с обсуждением вашей проблемы: https://habr.com/post/264189/

Comment: Пытался вставить код - не хватило символов...

Comment: В общем, тривиальный код на небыстром компе при карте 100*100 выполняется в пределах одной миллисекунды. При большей карте из-за высокой сложности  алгоритма время выполнения растет значительно, нужно упрощать в ущерб гарантированному пути. Код в коммент не влазит.

Comment: 250 мс у меня выполняется, если расчет делать каждый шаг на карте 1280*720 (на скринах карта 80*40 и попытки оптимизации), кроме того у меня будет каждый следующий уровень сложнее и врагов больше и как там будет с фпс я вообще боюсь представить. Статья вообще не понял че делает, задействует Vector3.Distance, которого у меня нет.. Почему так мало статей, неужели никто не задумывался как такое сделать или щас все на новых языках пишут, где это уже встроено?) Кстати код можно вставить в pastebin.com, его аналоги или прямо в ответ.

Comment: `Vector3.Distance, которого у меня нет` -  Расстояние между точками (евклидово расстояние) для игродела не должно составлять проблем.

Comment: Статей на эту тему море, особенно на английском. Общих решений нет потому, что все случаи имеют различные решения, серебряной пули нет. Если вы хотите считать траекторию для сетки 1280*720, то вам точно не подойдет алгоритм Ли. Вы исходно не сказали размер своей сетки, поэтому я и исходил из скриншотов. Для скриншотов этого алгоритма "за глаза". Граф путей надо пересчитывать для каждой цели, поэтому если противников много, но они все идут в одну точку, то можно считать пути один раз на кадр.

Comment: Если ваша сетка движения очень мелкая (попиксельное движение? а если разрешение поменяется?), то для каждой карты можно сделать "ключевые точки" и передвигать ботов по ним (это могут быть входы в комнаты, повороты коридоров и т.д.). Вес ребра - расстояние между ключевыми точками, между которыми можно двигаться по прямой. Далее такой же обход в ширину графа и поиск пути с минимальным весом. В общем, ваша задача - сократить количество вычислений, уменьшая возможное количество точек и ребер между ними. Для юнити есть готовые ассеты для прокладки маршрутов, но они имеют очень узкое применение.